# How to validate the extension "pdf"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, pdf, rails-activestorage

I need a validation to check the file extension, if uploaded file in ActiveStorage is pdf or not.

I tired with below validation, however an error message shows, doesn't matter which file extension (also pdf file)...

```
validate :user_file_type, if: :is_existing?
  def user_file_type
    extension = ['file/pdf']
    errors.add(:user_file, "must be a PDF") unless 
    user_file.blob.content_type.in?(extension)
  end

  def is_existing?
    self.user_file.attached?
  end
```

Does someone know how should I write the validation, so that an error message shows only if non-pdf was uploaded? Thanks

Comment: There is a gem for active storage validations: https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/active_storage_validations

Comment: WOW! It's working. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I added it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a gem for active storage validations: [active_storage_validations](https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/active_storage_validations)

I use this gem and I recommend it to you. You can use it like this:

```
validates :user_file, content_type: ['application/pdf']
```

Comment: Thanks!
I wrote as below and solved.
```
validates :user_file, attached: true, content_type: { in: 'application/pdf', message: 'is not a PDF' }
´´´